# Why does this XSL fails to retrieve value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

Following is **an extract of the XSL stylesheet** that I have written.
It says my '.xsl' is well formed but it somehow does not retrieve values from the XML, instead just pastes the header and table headings.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>GlenMark Pharma</title>
        </head>
        <h1 align="center"><font face="Monotype Corsiva" color="red">GlenMarkPharma</font></h1>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>ENAME</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                        <th>PWD</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="mobile" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="email" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="pwd" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Here is my XML doc:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MyfirstXsl.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE employees SYSTEM "Mydtd.dtd">
<me:employees xmlns:me="pavitar.dua@gmail.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="pavitar.dua@gmail.com Mycomplex.xsd">
    <me:employee empID="EMP101">
        <me:name>Vicky</me:name>
        <me:mobile>9870582356</me:mobile>
        <me:email>vicky@gmail.com</me:email>
        <me:pwd>&defPWD;</me:pwd>
    </me:employee>
</me:employees>
```

I have also tried writing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="me:name" /></td>
```

In the XSL since I have an **alias to the namespace in my XML Doc**.But it gives me an error of Invalid Pre-fix.I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post the context of your XSLT. Most likely, in the place where you have the `<xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">` code there are no nested `employees/employee` nodes.

Comment: Have you declared the "pavitar.dua@gmail.com" namespace in your stylesheet?

Comment: @mzjn- yes,and I've given it an alias "me"

Comment: @Pavitar, don't just say what you have done, please show us! Can't you provide a complete stylesheet that we can run?

Comment: @mzjn - OK now I have added the complete style sheet.Please check EDIT

Comment: @Pavitar: The currently accepted answer is not correct. It does not display the values of `name`, `mobile`, `email, and `pwd`. @Ondrej 's answer is correct. Please, accept the right answer.

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev -Yea I did that now thanks +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two namespace declarations into your XSLT:

- `xmlns:me="pavitar.dua@gmail.com"` to denote the input marktup;
- `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to denote the resulting markup.

And then change your XSLT to denote the source with the `me` prefix like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="me:employees/me:employee">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="me:name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="me:mobile" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="me:email" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="me:pwd" /></td>
     </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Also, consider using a “more XSLT-native” constructs:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>  <!-- instead of the for-each --!>
…
<xsl:template match="me:employee">
    <!-- include the table row here --!>
</xsl:template>
```

You will end up with a more versatile XSLT design. Bear in mind that XSLT is supposed to be *declarative* not procedural.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is unaware of the namespace used in your XML i.e. "pavitar.dua@gmail.com". Here is the modified XSL. Just added

> xmlns:me="pavitar.dua@gmail.com"

To your XSLT and verified it is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:me="pavitar.dua@gmail.com" version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>GlenMark Pharma</title>
            </head>
            <h1 align="center"><font face="Monotype Corsiva" color="red">GlenMarkPharma</font></h1>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>ENAME</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>EMAIL</th>
                            <th>PWD</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="me:employees/me:employee">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="mobile" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="email" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="pwd" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Maybe they have done that because you forget the namespace in the innermost `xsl:value-of`...

Comment: Yes but I just wanted to provide the direction. Still the down voter would have specified the reason :-(