# xslt remove highest level parent if child/child/node is empty

Tags: xml, xslt

Community;

I have tried many of the posts here to solve this problem. I keep going no where.
Any Help is Appreciated.

I have the following XMl:

```
 <SD>
   <I>
     <B>
       <A>SomeData</A>
       <Is>
         <Id/>
         <Id/>
         <Id/>
         <Id/>
         <Id/>
         <Id/>
       </Is>
     </B>
     <S>
       <D></D>
     </S>
     <D>
     .....
     </D>
   </I>
 </SD>
```

I need to delete  if I/S/D is empty or white-space.
So if I/S/D is empty, I should only have

```
    <SD>
    </SD>
```

I have tried but I do not get the desired result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What result did you get that doesn't match what you want?

Comment: You can't delete, only exclude.

Comment: xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="I/S[descendant::D='']"/>
    <xsl:template match="I[not(descendant::S/D='')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you have this matching template

```
<xsl:template match="I[not(descendant::S/D='')]"/>
```

But this will match **I** elements where **S/D** is not empty, which is the reverse of you what you want to do. What you can do is just this

```
<xsl:template match="I[not(S/D!='')]"/>
```

This will match empty **S/D** elements, as well as the case where there is no such element at all.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="I[not(S/D!='')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you use this, the following is output

```
<SD></SD>
```

Comment: when I remove xmlns=... the code works as it should, when this is part of the <SD> tag the I is still brought in

Comment: I figured it out used -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533656/why-does-this-xsl-fails-to-retrieve-value-from-xml)

Comment: When you have xmlns=... in your XML, it means all the elements in your XML are in a default namespace. This means you need to amend the XSLT to select elements in that namespace. At the moment the XSLT is looking for elements with no namespace.